# How to use the composer in kohana 3.3?

Tags: facebook, composer-php, kohana, kohana-3

Trying to connect the package: https://packagist.org/packages/facebook/php-sdk-v4

Doing so: php composer.phar require facebook / php-sdk-v4

There is a successful installation package

composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.24",
        "phing/phing": "dev-master",
        "facebook/php-sdk-v4": "4.1.*@dev"
    }
}
```

The file butstrap.fp before loading module adds:

```
require (DOCROOT.'vendor / autoload.php ');
```

In the right controller call:

```
FacebookSession :: setDefaultApplication ('APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET'); and I get the error:
```

ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'FacebookSession' not found

Why is that?

Tried to run

```
$ session = new FacebookSession (); , An error occurs:
```

ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'FacebookSession' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook SDK uses namespaces, and you are not using them. That's why the classes are not found: You have to add the namespace or import the class into your own namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Use full name for class, with namespace.

```
Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication ('APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET');
```

and

```
$session = new Facebook\FacebookSession();
```